# Не подключается массив

Tags: android, массивы

```
MainActivity.java
String[] name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name);

String.xml
<string name="petr">Петр</string>
<string name="vasiliy">Василий</string>

<string-array name="name">
        <item>@string/petr</item>
        <item>@string/vasiliy</item>
</string-array>
```

Не получается подключить массив из String.xml. 
Выбрасывает Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference.

Как может быть null??? Массив же есть.

Comment: Все нормально работает. Можно так использовать. Да и какая разница, просто строки в массиве тоже пробовал, такая же беда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это

```
String[] name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name);
```

поле в Activity, то вы обращаетесь к ресурсам, когда активити о них еще не знает. Вынесите инициализацию массива в onCreate

Comment: Дело было не в бобине. Спасибо Дмитрий.